# Length of a member in a structure

Tags: c

While trying out a simple program I am facing this difficulty ,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Student 
{
int id;
int marks; 
char fav_char; 
char name;
};


int main()
{
struct Student s1;
s1.id = 1;
s1.marks = 90;
s1.fav_char = 'Character';
s1.name = 'X';

printf("The favorite character is %c \n" , s1.fav_char);
printf("The name is %c" , s1.name);

return 0;
}
```

I get a warning that 'Character' is too long while for 'X' value it is showing no error .
Plus in the output I am getting only the last letter printed

Output is like
The favorite character is r
The name is X

Pls tell the reason as too why is the character length too long , and also the reason why only the last letter is being printed .

PS: I have just started learning coding . So please bear it if the doubt is too basic

Comment: `char x;` is a variable that occupies a single byte. If you want to work with strings you need a pointer to the memory area where that string resides. Thus `char *x;` instead, with the downside that you'd need to allocate memory. `char x[1234];` does this for you and reserves 1234 bytes somewhere. Be sure to allocate room for the zero terminator (`\0`=

Comment: This isn't how string handling works in C.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want to store *strings* instead of *single characters*.

Read the chapter dealing with strings in your learning material. Be aware that there is no real string type in C, that's the reason you need to use `strcpy`.

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNAME 100  // maximal length of names

struct Student
{
  int id;
  int marks;
  char fav_char[MAXNAME];  // you need an array of chars
  char name[MAXNAME];      // you need an array of chars
};


int main()
{
  struct Student s1;
  s1.id = 1;
  s1.marks = 90;
  strcpy(s1.fav_char, "Character");   // use strcpy
  strcpy(s1.name, "X");               // use strcpy

  printf("The favorite character is %s \n", s1.fav_char);  // use %s instead of %s
  printf("The name is %s", s1.name);                       // use %s instead of %s

  return 0;
}
```

Bonus: Unlike yours, this code is properly [indented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).